# Are site templates just packaged bundles of features, apps, and configuration?

Tags: site-template

I'm trying to figure out the "magic" of site templates. Are they just a packaged set of features and apps, or is there some magic "under the hood" that makes them what they are?

Put another way: if I created a "Team Site," could I spend a bunch of time modifying apps, features, and settings and turn it into a "Publishing Site"? Or is there some inaccessible setting/config that makes them what they are?

(Note that I would never want to actually do that, but is it possible?  If so, then it would prove/demonstrate that site templates aren't magic, they're just a bundle of features, apps, and settings that could theoretically be replicated manually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what they are. You can examine their XML manifests to see exactly what features, lists, etc. are being deployed.